# App sudden got a Timeout exception and Internal server error

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

The sign up and sign in function on my xamarin app sudden stopped working. It sometimes gives:

**Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:  occurred**

and other times:

**Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed. (Internal Server Error) occurred**

I didn't change anything on these pages to affect them. Only thing that happened was my azure subscription went out of date and I renewed it. The connection is still the same unless there's some setting I'm missing.

I'm sure the problem on both pages is the same so I'm just going to show my sign up page here. If you need to see my sign in, just let me know.

Edit 1: I added a try/catch and it always goes to the catch.

Edit 2: **The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

That comes up in the log, don't know why it all of a sudden keeps giving these exceptions, nothing I try shows any improvement.

Edit 3: Tried clean build, unistall, reinstall but now I'm at a loss. It worked fine up to today and now I get these problems mentioned above and nothing I do seems to fix it.

```
        EditText Username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        EditText Password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        EditText ConfirmPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtConfirmPassword);
        if (Password.Text == ConfirmPassword.Text)
        {
            try
            {
                string hashedPassword = PasswordStorage.CreateHash(Password.Text);
                string userName = Username.Text.Trim();
                users newU = new users { username = userName, password = hashedPassword };
                List<users> allUsers = await Client.GetTable<users>().ToListAsync();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Awaits table", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                users u = allUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == newU.username);
                if (u == null)
                {
                    DBHelper.InsertNewUser(newU);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "User " + newU.username + " created! You can now log in!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "User " + u.username + " already exists!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Time out", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: With Mobile Applications, you have to asume that the connection to the server might not work at any given time. It is so bad using a Distributed DB on the Device might be nesseary. At large, these Excpetions sound plain Exogenous in nature. The rare case you should handle. But I can not exclude 100% that they are not Boneheaded isntead. Here are two articles on proper exception handlin I link a lot. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code, you could optimize the query against your online table as follows:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net");
var users = await client.GetTable<users>().Where(u=>u.username == newU.username).ToListAsync();
if(users.Any())
{
   //user exists
}
else
{
   //add new user
}
```

For your scenario, I would recommend you [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to capture the detailed error. For C# backend, you could specify `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;` under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file, then you could retrieve the detailed error in the response. And you need to debug your code and use fiddler to capture the network traces, the error could be thrown by `Client.GetTable<users>().ToListAsync()` or `DBHelper.InsertNewUser(newU)`, so you need to troubleshoot by yourself. If you could not solve this issue, you could update the question with more detailed steps you tried and detailed request traces you retrieved for us to narrow down this issue.

Moreover, you could follow adrian hall's book about [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

Comment: I have it fixed now, I also did the optimisation of the query that you showed but keep getting "cannot convert generic types list". I added the "public static implicit operator" which VS suggested with an "throw new NotImplementedException();" within my getter and setter class. Now it keeps throwing that exception. I'm being stupid here and missing something, any ideas?

Comment: I just defined a simple `users` class. For your new issue, you could update your question or you'd better create a new question with the details (model definition,etc.)